# Rails 4.2: a form_tag with submit_tag - it seems the submit_tag is not needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit

I have seen examples like this:

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search products" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

But if I replace the submit_tag with just some standard html, like this:

```
    <%= text_field_tag ... same as above %>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

I can still submit the form using this button or pressing enter.

What then is the purpose of the submit_tag? Is it just a quick way to get a simple submit button (which obviously I didn't want, I wanted a magnifying glass button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a `submit_tag` is not only that it helps you write the HTML. It can be controlled directly by rails with access to `@variables` and other server side dynamics.